# Embedding Youtube video on comments

Tags: embed, youtube, comments, comments-template

In my posts, you can embed a video of Youtube by adding the link to the post. You don't have to do anything beside that.

On my comments, I can't do the same thing. Is it possible to embed Youtube video's by putting the link only (or a different manner, but I prefer the first), and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the comments to oEmbed. Here's a small plugin that you can use as MU-Plugin or normal plugin and that should explain what's going on pretty well.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;
/* Plugin Name: (#105942) oEmbed Comments */

add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpse_105942_oembed_comments', 0 );
function wpse_105942_oembed_comments( $comment )
{
    add_filter( 'embed_oembed_discover', '__return_false', 999 );

    $comment = $GLOBALS['wp_embed']->autoembed( $comment );

    remove_filter( 'embed_oembed_discover', '__return_false', 999 );

    return $comment;
}
```

Comment: i think `$comment_text` in your code should be `$comment` to work properly or your can return `$comment_text` instead of `$comment`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jetpack plugin](http://jetpack.me/) for embedding Youtube video's link in comment.

**Important Links:**

[Shortcode Embeds](http://jetpack.me/support/shortcode-embeds/)

[Embedding youtube link](http://en.support.wordpress.com/videos/youtube/)

Comment: Answers should be more than links.

Answer (score -1):

To have them embedded nicely in comments with width responsive try fitvid

http://wordpress.org/plugins/fitvids-for-wordpress/

Works like a charm with the code snippet from above:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;
/* Plugin Name: (#105942) oEmbed Comments */

add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpse_105942_oembed_comments', 0 );
function wpse_105942_oembed_comments( $comment )
{
    add_filter( 'embed_oembed_discover', '__return_false', 999 );

    $comment = $GLOBALS['wp_embed']->autoembed( $comment );

    remove_filter( 'embed_oembed_discover', '__return_false', 999 );

    return $comment;
}
```

Comment: Low quality posts are those that just have an outgoing link. Please summon the most important (code) bits in here.

Comment: i dont really understand what you mean. this is a link to a wordpress plugin, how should i post the code?